# how to sort select DropDownList items in mvc 4 webgrid?

Tags: model-view-controller, webgrid

I'm working on mvc$ webgrid viewer, my grid viewer lists all columns exactlly as I want but there is one problem when I sort grid content by clicking on the hyperlink of the column names it sorts for all the columns except the drop down menu or `DropDownList` in mvc viwer.
[![mvc4 webgrid  view screenshoot][1]][1]

```
DropDownList is not sorted as the other column values.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call a function that have the set of `selectlist` items. for example, in my case it works when I make  the webgrid as follows:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "ContractFileNamesList", header: "ContractFileNamesList", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("filename",
 , "-- Select One --"))
```

especially,

> (IEnumerable)Model.ContractBOModel[rowVal -
>   1].FileNameListsFunction(fileNameStr);